# Can my PC handle a Nividia GTX 750 Ti?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

I am willing to update my graphics card to Nividia GTX 750 Ti but I am confused about the power supply and the motherboard if they can support it or not.

**Motherboard**

```
System Manufacture: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
System Model: To be filled by O.E.M
```

**Power Supply**

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ma7oKPU.jpg]

**PC Specs**

```
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3450 CPU @ 3.10GHz (4 CPUs), ~3.5GHz
Memory: 4096MB RAM
Card name: NVIDIA GeForce 210 
Manufacturer: NVIDIA
Chip type: GeForce 210
```

So can my PC support the Nividia GTX 750 Ti? If not, what shall I upgrade and what to?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

750 ti requires at least a 300 watt power supply. Your power supply is a 350 watt, so you can do it.

Comment: so, the 750Ti needs 300W just to run? Where's the proof?

Comment: @TD.512 http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-750-ti/specifications

Comment: @corn3lius - I can promise you that the 750TI does not consume 300 Wattage at full load.

Answer (score 2):

#### Yes, your computer can accept this video card.

- [The GeForce GTX 750 Ti needs just 60 W](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-750-ti/specifications), which is [about 30 W more than what the GeForce 210 requires](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-210/specifications). The reference version does not require an auxiliary power connector. This is well inside the limits of your PSU (350 W total, 19 A on +12V).
- An overclocked version of the GTX 750 Ti may draw up to 10–15 W more, which would still be within the limits of your PSU. However, some overclocked cards require auxiliary power, which your PSU most likely does not support. Be sure to check the specifications for the card before you buy.
- The real power hog on this machine is the CPU. [The i5-3450 has a TDP of 77 W.](http://ark.intel.com/products/65511/Intel-Core-i5-3450-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_50-GHz) Considering the power consumption of the other components, your system probably wouldn't need much more than 200 W under load.